# Create a key in the registry and set it's value with the installation path with installshield

Tags: c#, registry, key, installshield

I wrote a WinForms app and I want to make setup project for this and I want to use installshield for this, it's the first time that I use installshield, now I want to configure my setup project to create a key in registry and it's value is the path of installation that the user browsed, how can I set the value of key with the path that the user entered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the registry view to define a Hive \ Key \ String \ Value path and set it's data to a value of [INSTALLDIR].

Comment: can you explain more for me,i'm beginer with instalshild,thanks alot.